# Prove from first principles that the following sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis

$a_n=\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}$.
I know that $(a_n)\rightarrow0$, but when I go about proving it, I don't get anywhere.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Then $|a_n-0|=|\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}|=$ (something I'm clearly missing) $<\epsilon$.

If someone could bridge the gap, that'd be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you prove that $1/(4n^2-3)\le 1/2n^2$, at least for $n$ large enough? Does this help?

Comment: Note that if $n\ge 2$, then $4n^2-3=3n^2+n^2-3\gt 3n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit of awkwardness in this question.  To illustrate it I will first do a slightly simpler question.

**Problem**.  If
$$a_n=\frac{5n}{4n^2+3}$$
then $a_n\to0$.

**Proof**.  Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Choose $N=5/(4\varepsilon)$.  For any $n>N$ we have
$$\eqalign{|a_n-0|
  &=\frac{5n}{4n^2+3}\cr
  &<\frac{5n}{4n^2}\cr
  &=\frac{5}{4n}\cr
  &<\frac{5}{4N}\cr
  &=\varepsilon\ .\cr}$$
We have shown: for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n-0|<\varepsilon$.  By definition, this means that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Comment**.  The obvious question is, where did $N=5/(4\varepsilon)$ come from?  The answer is that you would do some rough working first: you would do the algebra to get as far as
$$|a_n-0|<\frac{5}{4N}$$
and then you would say, we want this to equal $\varepsilon$, so what should $N$ be?  This is good for rough work but would not be so good as a formal proof since a proof should have all the logic clearly set out and in the right order.  So we would then go back and write down a proof as I have done above.

**Another question**.  How did we get the line
$$\frac{5n}{4n^2+3}<\frac{5n}{4n^2}\ ?$$
Well, the denominator on the LHS is bigger than that on the RHS, so the whole LHS is smaller than the RHS.  And why did we do this anyway? - well just to make the expression simpler.  Keep this in mind and we'll go back to the question you asked.

If
$$a_n=\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}$$
we would like to say in the same way
$$|a_n-0|=\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}<\frac{5n}{4n^2}\ .$$
Unfortunately the last step is now not true, so we have to be a bit smarter.  One way to do it is this: since we are interested in $n\to\infty$, we may as well assume that $n>2$.  Then $n^2>3$ and we have
$$4n^2-3=3n^2+(n^2-3)>3n^2\ .$$
Therefore if $n>N$ (note, we still don't know what $N$ will be) then we have
$$|a_n-0|=\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}<\frac{5n}{3n^2}=\frac{5}{3n}<\frac{5}{3N}\ .$$
As before, this will be equal to $\varepsilon$ if $N=5/(3\varepsilon)$.  Remembering that we also need $n>2$ we can do the following.

**Problem**.  If
$$a_n=\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}$$
then $a_n\to0$.

**Proof**.  Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Choose $N=\max(2,5/(3\varepsilon))$.  That is, $N=2$ or $N=5/(3\varepsilon)$, whichever is bigger.  Let $n>N$.  Note that this means **both** $N>2$ **and** $n>5/(3\varepsilon)$.  Therefore we have
$$4n^2-3=\cdots>3n^2$$
and
$$|a_n-0|=\cdots<\cdots=\varepsilon\ .$$

See if you can fill in the dots and write out a complete proof.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use that $\displaystyle\frac{5n}{4n^2-3}\le \frac{5n}{4n^2-3n^2}=\frac{5n}{n^2}=\frac{5}{n}$.

Comment: Why not just use $4n^2-3n^2$ in the first inequality?

Comment: good suggestion - I'll do that instead!